# What is the doctype for XHTML5 (XML serialization of HTML5)?

Tags: html, xhtml, doctype

What doctype should be specified for XML serialization of HTML5?

Keeping file extension as html can I tell the browser that the content is XHTML5?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: you have a problem, and you're trying to solve it by serving up some of the files as XHTML. Bringing up new problems. So, what's the original problem you're trying to solve? Let's look at that first.

Answer (score 5):

The "doctype" of XHTML5 is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Strictly speaking, HTML5 has no doctype. It only has a "look at me, I'm an HTML5 document" marker that happens to resemble a doctype declaration for the purposes of triggering standards mode in web browsers. Since XHTML5 is, as you state, nothing more than an XML serialization of HTML5, its "doctype" is the same as HTML5's.

If you're asking about the *MIME type*, then that is application/xhtml+xml, as usual for an XHTML document. The doctype has no influence whatsoever on whether a document is served as HTML tag soup or as XML.

Comment: Its due to the validation issues I asked this question. There are validation errors due to e.g. void elements having separate close tags which are otherwise valid in xml

Comment: And some html files may have html5, but other XHtml5, so I cannot just specify mime types. Is then xhtml extension the best option?

Comment: @Nitesh: Your first mistake is in serving your site as part HTML and part XHTML. No one ever does that. No one. If you're doing that because you can't make up your mind which flavor to go with, I'll decide for you: HTML.

Answer (score 1):

> What doctype should be specified for XML serialization of HTML5?

From [the docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/xhtml.html#the-xhtml-syntax):

> XML documents may contain a DOCTYPE if desired, but this is not required to conform to this specification. This specification does not define a public or system identifier, nor provide a formal DTD.

So there is no standard DTD for it, so you shouldn't provide any Doctype (unless you write a DTD first).

---

> Keeping file extension as html can I tell the browser that the content is XHTML5?

File extensions are irrelevant on the WWW. The Content-Type HTTP response headers should be `application/xhtml+xml`.

Comment: When opening files from local file system, the extension does make difference. More importantly its due to the validation issues I asked this question. There are validation errors due to e.g. void elements having separate close tags which are otherwise valid in xml

Comment: "When opening files from local file system, the extension does make difference. " — That is an atypical use for XHTML, since you didn't mention it in the question it was reasonable to assume you were talking about the WWW. Software uses file extensions to determine the file type on a local system, so don't give them .html file extensions.

Comment: "There are validation errors due to e.g. void elements having separate close tags which are otherwise valid in xml" — That is something else you didn't mention. You will need to find an XHTML aware validator. That could be a standard XML validator if you wrote a DTD for XHTML. There isn't a standard DTD for XHTML.

Comment: And some html files may have html5, but other XHtml5, so I cannot just specify mime types.

Answer (score 0):

Any use of XHTML should imply it is now an XML document. That's the only requirement for XHTML, though many websites have delivered XHTML as "text/html" mime-type (as set by the web server), though it should have been "application/xhtml+xml". As such your web server should be configured to deliver XHTML as XML. Once it is delivered as an XML document type your web page will fail to parse in the web browser if its not perfectly formed and validated XML.